# Limiting HTML multiple select input to only consecutive elements (+shift only, ignoring +ctrl)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a standard HTML multiple select field, much like the W3 schools example:

```html
<select name="cars" size="4" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

My functionality requires the ability to select multiple items (shift + click) but only those consecutive to each other. In other words, ignoring the [ctrl + click] functionality,

**For example:**

Allowed:

```
Volvo
Saab
Fiat
```

Not allowed:

```
Volvo
Fiat
```

Any ideas? I can do data validation & rejection in JS but I'd rather prevent it to begin with.

Comment: So you currently cannot select consecutive elements? Is that the problem you need a workaround for?

Comment: I ***can*** select consecutive options, using click+shift. My issue is that I need to limit to ***only*** consecutive elements.

Using ctrl+click, the user is able to select multiple, non-consecutive elements, which is what I don't want

Comment: I don't know if pure HTML5 will be able to achieve this. I will do some digging but I think js may be unfortunately be your way out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not natively implemented in the [`select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) HTML component, you'll definitely need JS to work around this (using jQuery).

To do so, you could disable selection when CTRL key is pressed:

```
let ctrlKeyPressed = false;

$(function() {
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Meta' || e.key == 'CTRL') {
        ctrlKeyPressed = true;
    }
  }

  document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Meta' || e.key == 'CTRL') {
        ctrlKeyPressed = false;
    }
  }
});

$("option").mousedown(function(e) {
  if (ctrlKeyPressed) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

You'll find the full working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrdy9sh/2/)

Comment: Thanks @lukas. I thought that was the case. Thanks for the snippet